# Slow distro upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I've been upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04. I thought it was going quite normal. However it has been "installing the upgrades" for over 70 hours. Yes, over three days. My system is almost frozen and it seems( I can't check) that it is eating most of my CPU but as it is frozen I can't check.

How much longer should I wait for it and can I cancel at this stage? If I can, how and if I can't, how long will it take? I am quite worried.

EDIT: solved thanks to the_Seppi. I am very grateful.

Comment: Open `gnome-system-monitor` and provide information on how much swap space your system is using during the upgrade. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: One extra little problem is that I cannot open the terminal, and if I do it just shows me a little purple window with a white box, and it doesn't execute any commands. Also I have 3 GB of RAM.

Comment: Please - before you kill your system like suggested in some answers - change the tty by pressing <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, typing `cat /proc/meminfo` and posting `MemTotal`, `MemFree`, `MemAvailable`, `SwapTotal` and `SwapFree` (change back to the default view by pressing <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)

Comment: I've already killed the system :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really shouldn't take this long. I assume something went wrong and it's unlikely that further waiting will be of any use. Most likely your system didn't survive the presumably failed release upgrade and only a new installation might be able to get a fully working system again.

So the steps that seem apt now are these:

1. Cancel the upgrade (If necessary using the power button)
2. Create a bootable USB stick or DVD with a 14.04 ISO from within your Windows.
3. Install 14.04 from the USB stick. **Do not select the upgrade method**, but go the Something Else route.
4. Delete the Ubuntu partition, if you indeed don't have any personal files on it.
5. Create a new EXT4 partition in the now free space. Select it for the installation of the system.
6. Select `sda` for the boot loader, if you're using legacy BIOS or your EFI partiton (probably `sda1`), if you're running an UEFI system.
7. Start the installation.

If you want to go through a release upgrade again in the future (a full reinstallation gives you a clean system without any remains of the previous onw), you may want to run it from a terminal or TTY with the command `do-release-upgrade`. In doing so, you'll see everything that is done, and you will also know about any errors that occur.

Comment: How do I cancel it? It said at the "setting new software channels" part that I cannot cancel it after that point. Also my hard drive also has Windows on it so wiping it is not desirable. I also haven't got any files in my Ubuntu release so uninstalling it is OK. I don't have a USB however so I can't really use that either.

Comment: I'll adapt my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps user2904527, Mine took about 12 hours to do the same.

It could you either your
1) Internet connection or 
2) No. of packages you have, that needs to be upgraded.

Easier option is to backup your data & Use Ubuntu 14 Installer from USB/CD....